# Important data structures in search

Tags: .net, search, data-structures, f#

I'm interested in teaching myself different data structures, something I currently know very little about.  My plan is to implement a few key structures so I understand how they work.  I'm looking for suggestions on important data structures to start with.

I'm primarily interested in data structures that are relevant to search applications (e.g. Google / Lucene) and the general trade-off between delayed computation and precomputation.  I'm also interested in distributed data structures -- data structures that can scale across hundreds / thousands of servers -- and probabilistic data structures -- data structures that help finding an approximate answer but do not need to always be correct.

Wikipedia has a [list of data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures).  I am currently considering:

- Hash table
- B+-Tree
- R-Tree
- KD-Tree
- Radix-Tree
- Bloom filter

Are there better choices?

Finally, is there any (major) problem with implementing these structures in a language like F#?

Comment: Implement an ordered dictionary as well. I personally would use Java or Python or .Net or C++ ...

Comment: @lpthnc : .NET is not a language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very ambitious.  I voted your question up just for its scope.

MIT has an [on-line algorithms and data structures course](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-046JFall-2005/VideoLectures/).  The [companion book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) is a classic.  I'm not sure if it addresses the distributed and probabilistic features, but they'll give you an excellent grounding in the fundamentals.

I'd add red-black tree, hash tables, patricia trie, and skip lists to your agenda.

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to tackle this sort of thing with a functional language you should have a look at *Purely Functional Data Structures* by Chris Okasaki.  Basic lesson is: the data structures you are familiar with for imperative programming may not be the best choices for functional programming.  I expect there's a lot of similar material to be Googled for.

Answer (score 3):

For search, algorithms are more important than data structures. When searching a large search space you often have to have sophisticated methods for pruning the search space.

You might look at classic search algorithms such as alpha-beta, A*, AO*.

Then look at something like iteratively deepening search.

In search algorithms, things like stacks and linked lists (which are really a form of a stack) and trees are more important than hash tables, B-trees etc. Of course, you will undoubtedly have hash tables in there, but it won't be the heart of the algorithm.

Here's some more important search algorithsm:

1. B* search
2. backtracking
3. beam search
4. best-first search
5. bidirectional search
6. hill-climbing search
7. simulated annealing
8. IDA*
9. iterative deepening depth-first search
10. mini-max search
11. nearest neighbor search
12. spreading activation
13. state space search (not a technique, just a way of conceptualizing a problem).

As far as specific data structures for search goes, you really don't need any. Basically, you just need your regular tool kit of data structures - trees, hashes, lists.

Comment: I disagree that for search algorithms are more important that data structures. The two really go hand in hand.

Comment: I think he's looking for information retrieval algorithms first, numeric optimization is more helpful once you already have the basics working.

Comment: "More important" is perhaps a mis-statement. I should have said that there is more search-specific material to learn in the algorithm literature, than in data structures, because a relatively small number of data structures that are commonly used for other purposes will for the most part suffice, but there is a huge body of literature on different search algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have very little knowledge on DS I think you should start with Lists (Single and doubly Linked Lists).

Then you can study various tree data structures.

Also since you are interested on DS related to search, I think you should study B-tree+ trees and hash table.

[The Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/) is a good book to learn more about algorithms.